# What's the purpose of sitting down in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

The wastelands and the various settlements within Fallout 4 is full of chairs, sofas, benches, and various other items that allow you to sit on them. Does sitting actually have a purpose or is it just an alternate to sleeping but without the "Well Rested" bonuses?

What's the purpose of sitting down in Fallout 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Waiting) one must be sitting to wait in the game. In previous Bethesda games you could just wait by standing in a location unless involved in a few situations like combat or dialog. Since you might be in an area doing something that is time sensitive and have no way of finding a bed to rest, you just need to find a place to sit and you can wait. To wait, you have to sit and then bring up the wait menu. On PC, it is reached by [hitting 'T'](http://www.shacknews.com/article/92104/how-to-wait-in-fallout-4)

Comment: Furthermore, of you sit down the "wait" option will appear on screen, rompting the player for the correct button on console

Comment: Timelord64's (omg) comment is also valid for PC ; like on all the menus, the hotkey is visible between parenthesis : ( T )