# Are you able to "wait"?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 3, Skyrim, etc. there was the ability to wait in game for a particular number of hours. I've tried every button combination and looked at the control scheme, however, there does not seem to be a "Wait" option. Is sleeping the only way to pass time?

Comment: Related: [What's the purpose of sitting down in Fallout 4?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242706/52800)

Comment: @kalina ah I checked for any similar questions and did not see that one. Worth keeping this question around or should I delete it?

Comment: It might be marked as a duplicate due to the answer over there answering both, but the question should definitely stay.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently, there is a way to wait without having to use a bed. Unfortunately, this is not something you are able to do standing. By sitting in a chair, an option icon pops up with a "Wait" option. Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah sitting in a chair seems to be the only way to trigger a "wait"

Comment: I've noticed that this does not work with all chairs. I can't wait in the stools in front of the noodle-serving robot in Diamond City, for instance. It's not just chairs either. I've waited on a bench.